Should I admit that I didn't meet a deadline due to stress from personal issues?
Last month I had a very difficult time (had to decide how our family property will be split between me and my brother and sister), and although it may sound weird, it was so stressful for me that I have not been able to properly work. This saddens me, because I have a great boss, we enjoy working together and he trusts in me. (I am on a postdoc position on University, he is professor only 10 years older). Now my boss sent me an email asking how is it with results, for which I had a deadline till the end of May. It seems he is only asking about current status, not asking why I didn't, not pushing at all.
Should I be honest and tell him that I was stressed from family issues so that's the reason why I didn't meet the deadline?
My reasons for telling him so:

I want to have relationship where we can trust each other. I don't want to make up false reasons, like that work got complicated etc.

Chances are it becomes clear that I was slacking for some reason, and in that case I don't want him to think that this is my standard and I was just slacking for no reason; I want him to know that I am motivated otherwise, just now I had a difficult time for good reasons.


My reasons for not telling him so:

He is a high-performance worker, so I am not sure if he would understand (I would tell him only "stress from family issues", nothing more detailed).

Thinking that maybe he is only interested in the results.


I have a dilemma about this. What is your opinion?

this is academia question, not a workplace

So your deadline was in May but nearly a third of a month has gone by, did you give your supervisor a new timeline, when you knew you wouldn’t complete your work? You don’t seem motivated since you have not reached out yourself with a more realistic timeline for your work. You knew you were struggling with your family affairs and wouldn’t complete the work on time.

@gnat - academia is a workplace too. The fact this is in academia does not mean it is not an issue in every other workplace on Earth.

@JonCuster this was discussed many times over at meta, for example here

@gnat - if you remove the remark about this being a postdoc position between brackets, you would not even know this is in Academia, making this question applicable in almost any workplace

@AsheraH without this remark question would become inappropriate for Stack Exchange at all. Questions need to provide context allowing people provide specific answers tailored to askers situation

Honesty - always.
Be prepare to give him a reason to trust you that you won't do it again. When I say won't do it again, I am referring to LACK OF COMMUNICATION. That is the issue.
We are all humans and we have problems that will cause us to not meet deadlines sometimes. We owe it to those we work with to be honest and as soon as we think/know that we are going to not meet a deadline to let them know.
They might not be happy about it. But it is much better than being sandbagged.
Trust is hard to earn and easy to lose.
Only you and not random internet people can decide how much to tell him. But trust your gut. Honesty is always better than BS.
Keep in mind, uncertainty is what lack of communications causes. That is what to want to assure him that you won't do again.
Let him know you feeling overwhelmed got in your way (if true) messed up your ability to keep him in the loop and you've learned a painful lesson (again only if true).
I hope you are doing well and good luck going forward.

It also turns out that many people have been through similar situations and will understand. Everyone who works for me knows my wife had cancer a few years back. Everyone knows my father passed away a few months ago. Why? Because I told them so they would understand why I'm not around as much as usual. And in turn I hope they tell me so I can easily understand that their attention is elsewhere until things are better. Bosses are human too.

@JonCuster Exactly how I operate, I wish I could give you more than just one +1. I'd never really considered it before, it's just what I do, however recently someone told me that I invest a lot of myself in my people, that's why they like working for me. Trust and communication, that's really all it takes

Let him know you feeling overwhelmed got in your way (if true) messed up your ability to keep him in the loop and you've learned a painful lesson TMI. 'Just answer the question'. See @Pete B's answer.

If it was me, I would start off with something like this:

The project is not complete, but section A is almost done, it needs a bit more Y. Section B only needs to be integrated with A.  Section C needs the most work but the work on A and B need to be completed first.
I need one week to complete A and another week to complete the A and B integration.  After that I can give a better timeline of when the project will be completed.

In other words, answer the question he is asking.  He wants to know the current status, and how much longer it will take to be completed.  This is not being dishonest it is giving him what he is asking for.
Only if he presses why, you are at this stage would I give details about a personal problem going on in your life.  Otherwise, there is no need.

I tend to agree. Explaining in any detail, unless they ask, can come across as making excuses, which is not a great look. "Life has been messy and I've been distracted/overloaded, sorry, here's where we are and when I think it'll be done" is sufficient; I'd wait for them to ask for more details or if they can help before going into details.

@keshlam ."Life has been messy and I've been distracted/overloaded...."  I'd say that was more than necessary, but asking how is it with results? , 10 days after the deadline seems to be gently asking for an explanation, so it's probably appropriate to say something, without going into detail.

I don't see 10 days after deadline in the question. And iin what timescale? Ten days late in a year-long project is peanuts. Especially if it hasn't been blocking anyone else from making progress. Context matters.
